# Changing the type (interpretation) of cv::Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

For whatever reason, I have a `.tiff` image which is incorrectly input by OpenCV `cv::imread` as `CV_16U` type instead `CV_16S`. I know it is incorrect, because my data was explained to me (the image should contain dummy values of -9999 and a positive max value), and I get the correct values when inputing in `Matlab`.

I can still handle it through e.g. the `.at<type>` function myself as I know the real type, so I can use `.at<short>`. However, the `cv::Mat::type()` is wrong which is not desirable if I use other functions for further processing which might rely on this parameter (where the processing might depend on `cv::Mat::type()`).

How can I *change the `cv::Mat::type()` without converting* the image? That is, I do not want the values to be re-calculated from the `unsigned short` to a `short` representation, but simply the *way they are read* to be changed.

**How do I change the `cv::Mat::type()` associated to the image.** (but not simply convert the image to a different type).

Here is some example code and it's output to illustrate the problem:

```
cv::Mat test = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
if (test.type() == CV_16U){ // true
    std::cerr << (short)(*std::min_element(test.begin<short>(),
                                           test.end<short>()))
              << std::endl;
    std::cerr << (short)(*std::max_element(test.begin<short>(),
                                           test.end<short>()))
              << std::endl;
    // output is OK, "-9999" and "1645"

    std::cerr << (unsigned short)
                 (*std::min_element(test.begin<unsigned short>(),
                                    test.end<unsigned short>()))
              << std::endl;
    std::cerr << (unsigned short)
                 (*std::max_element(test.begin<unsigned short>(),
                                    test.end<unsigned short>()))
              << std::endl;
    // output is not OK: "1" and "55537"

    cv::Mat test2;
    test.convertTo(test2, CV_16S);
    // also tried:
    // test.assignTo(test2, CV_16S);

    std::cerr << (short)(*std::min_element(test2.begin<short>(),
                                           test2.end<short>()))
              << std::endl;
    std::cerr << (short)(*std::max_element(test2.begin<short>(),
                                           test2.end<short>()))
              << std::endl;
    // output is not OK: "1" and "32767"

    test.type = CV_16U; // what I would like to do
}
```

Comment: @BeyelerStudios it's not a bug, opencv doesn't know whether the contents are signed or unsigned and sets it to unsigned by default

Comment: you can always construct a second matrix `cv::Mat actual(test.size(), CV_16S, test.ptr());` (`test` must be continuous for this, see [ptr](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr)), but that kind of stinks too :)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Can I somehow force it to set it to signed on input? I can see how there would be no way to determine it from the data...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios The copy works as intended. Not ideal to copy the data, but I will use this unless I find a better solution. Tyvm.

Comment: watch out: the matrix constructor taking the **data** parameter does **not copy**, you'll need to keep both matrices or the original image around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV leaves its data members public by default (though you generally don't want to mess with them yourself). Go ahead and give this a try; if it works Great! if not well...

**Warning:** untested and hackish solution

```
test.flags = (test.flags & ~CV_MAT_TYPE_MASK) | CV_16S;
```