# Save integer CV_32S image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am working with **TIF** images containing signed integer data. After successfully inputing one and processing it I need to output the image in the same format (input and output both **.tif* files).

For the input, I know that *OpenCV does not know if the data is signed or unsigned, so it assumes unsigned*. Using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258248/changing-the-type-interpretation-of-cvmat-image) solves that problem (switching the type of `cv::Mat` by hand).

However, when I output the image and load it again, I do not get the expected result. The file contains multiple segments (groups of pixels), and the format is as follows (**I must use this format**):

- all pixels not belonging to any segment have the value `-9999`
- all the pixels belonging to a single segment have the same positive integer value
- (e.g. all pixels of 1st segment have value `1`, second `2` etc)

And here is the example code:

```
void ImageProcessor::saveSegments(const std::string &filename){
    cv::Mat segmentation = cv::Mat(workingImage.size().height,
                                   workingImage.size().width,
                                   CV_32S, cv::Scalar(-9999));

    for (int i=0, szi = segmentsInput.size(); i < szi; ++i){
        for (int j=0, szj = segmentsInput[i].size(); j < szj; ++j){
            segmentation.at<int>(segmentsInput[i][j].Y,
                                 ssegmentsInput[i][j].X) = i+1;
        }
    }
    cv::imwrite(filename, segmentation);
}
```

You can assume that all the variables (e.g. `workingImage`, `segmentsInput`) exist as global variables.

Using this code, when I input the image and examine the values, most of the values are set to `0` while the ones that are set take a full range of integer values (in my example I had 20 segments).

Comment: What format are you saving your matrix in ? JPEG ?

Comment: @Sunreef as I said in my original question, it is all in TIF format

Comment: You can't save integer matrices directly with imwrite. As the documentation states: "Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function."

Comment: @Sunreef I see. Can you think of any workaround for this which would still allow me to save images in the required output format? (That is not getting into the TIFF documentation and outputting the file by hand)

Comment: did you try `libtiff`? http://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/638-f1999/libtiff_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can't save integer matrices directly with imwrite. As [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite) states: "Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function."

However, what you could do it to convert your `CV_32S` matrix to a `CV_8UC4` and save it as a PNG with no compression. Of course, this is a bit unsafe since [endianness](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) comes into play and may change your values between different systems or compilers (especially since we're talking about signed integers here). If you use always the same system and compiler, you can use this:

```
cv::Mat segmentation = cv::Mat(workingImage.size().height,
                               workingImage.size().width,
                               CV_32S, cv::Scalar(-9999));
cv::Mat pngSegmentation(segmentation.rows, segmentation.cols, CV_8UC4, (cv::Vec4b*)segmentation.data);
std::vector<int> params;
params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
params.push_back(0);
cv::imwrite("segmentation.png", pngSegmentation, params);
```

Comment: Tyvm, I'll give it a go and see how this works. But, as these files should be usable by other software as well (e.g. the one that produced the original TIF files), I am thinking I might need to settle for a different format at the end.

Comment: If you're working with TIFF images, 16-bit matrices are not enough ? You can save those with imwrite. @penelope

Comment: @Sunreef do you mean by endianness, that the saved image can be seen as corrupt file in other systems?

Answer (score 0):

I also save opencv mats as tifs but i don`t use the opencv tif solution. I include the libtiff lib on my own (i think libtiff is also used in opencv) and than you can use the following code to save as tiff

```
TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("file.tif", "w");

        if (tif != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
            {
                TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, TIFF_UINT64_T(x));  // set the width of the image                             
                TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, TIFF_UINT64_T(y));    // set the height of the image                         
                TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);   // set number of channels per pixel
                TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 32);    // set the size of the channels 32 for CV_32F                                  
                TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, i, pages);
                TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT, SAMPLEFORMAT_IEEEFP); // for CV32_F

                for (uint32 row = 0; row < y; row++)
                {
                    TIFFWriteScanline(tif, &imageDataStack[i].data[row*x*32/ 8], row, 0);
                }
                TIFFWriteDirectory(tif);
            }
        }
```

imageDataStack is a vector of cv::Mat objects. This code works for me to save tiff stacks.

Answer (score 0):

as @Sunreef said you can't with Opencv but here is how to write it with simple c:

```
cv::Mat m(600, 800, CV_32S);
FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/1.raw", "w");
fwrite(m.data, m.total()*m.depth(), 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

and read it with python:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.fromfile('/tmp/1.raw', dtype='int32')
m = m.reshape(600, 800)
```